Downvoting closed questions from newcomers: how can we address it?
I've noticed that bad questions from newcomers often not only get closed quickly, but get downvoted.  The downvoting often happens after the question is closed.  Helping some of them with chat, I've noticed that it's very easy for these downvotes to lock out a newcomer, preventing them from asking new questions, even after we've helped them understand what a good question looks like.
Per the help documentation, they're supposed to refine their existing question instead.  But refining it enough to not only be "okay," but worthy of upvotes is excruciating.  Doubly so because the algorithms quickly bury closed questions.
What can we tell newcomers to encourage them to be good Physics.SE citizens after making a mistake?  How can we help them get their standing back so that they can start asking good questions.  The only answer I have been able to find is "wait 6 months, and the algorithm unblocks you."  I doubt anyone has ever waited; we're not the only player in the game.
The best answer is probably to answer other's questions, but in most cases of these close/downvote patterns I've seen, they often do not have the physics background to farm enough rep to ask questions again.

AFAIK, the question ban is not installed after a single question but several poor contributions. The way you're writing this, it seems like it is pushed on new users with a single poorly-received question (by using singular 'question' everywhere).

@KyleKanos In a particular case, I remember it being a single question.  However, now that you question it, I should go check my evidence to make sure I'm not just misremembering.

The question ban only kicks in after many poorly-received questions; not just a single one. Note that you may be forgetting deleted questions.

Extending Vincent's comment, a user's deleted questions are not visible to normal users, so you can't exactly tell unless you've bookmarked all the links to all of a user's questions, you're going to be misled by their profile.

Note that new users sometimes also fail to realize that "multiple questions" includes deleted questions.

Speaking of this, my first meta post got -7.

@Ritzthephysibeast have you read the comments in your post and taken them to heart?

Yh, that's the problem, usually comments criticize.

Agreed that excessive downvoting should be rare, although I’m puzzled to think that a single massive downvote could lock an account.  Admittedly I don’t keep track of suspended accounts.
Of course there is no practical way to deal with impatient users who don’t bother searching the site or are just careless, but in my book there is nothing gained by locking the account of a new user unless there are exceptional circumstances.  As others have suggested, there are likely deleted questions.
See also this old question of mine on a nearly identical topic.
There is right now this related question also on meta and I think if we fix the companion question we’re some ways to fixing the problem you allude to here.  At least better direction to new users and a bit of patience on the part of the community should allow the well-meaning new users to avoid being locked out.

More often than not, I tend give new users some leeway and vote to reopen their questions rather than vote to close them. Sometimes, the question is definitely unclear and impossible to answer as presented. If I ask for clarification from the OP and none is forthcoming or if I see repeated requests for clarification from other users and no response from the OP, I will downvote the question as a warning "shot across the bow" in order to send the message "sort this mess out". However, I was not aware that my downvotes could lead to a new user being locked out of the site and that was not my intention. Perhaps I should avoid downvoting in future as I genuinely try to be friendly and helpful to newcomers.
I am not sure how to make the site more tolerant of new users. Perhaps it should be made impossible to downvote already closed questions. The user is already injured and on the floor. I don't see why we should continue to kick the user when they are already down.
Sometimes it seems obvious that people are downvoting questions, because the question contains assumptions that are not correct. I don't think that is good practice as newcomers should not be expected to have a full and correct knowledge of the physical principles involved in their question. Clearly, if they did, there would be no need for them to ask any questions on the subject all. Surely it would be better and friendlier to provide a short answer explaining where their misconception are.

I'm sorry, the implication that users who follow how the site works with down votes and question closure are not being tolerant or friendly is pretty bad here. Bans only happen after repeated poor questions. If you see a bad question, you should downvote and/or vote to close no matter who is making the post. You can still leave a comment that is friendly and encouraging to help them out though. That's how the site improves; not letting bad content through. Downvotes and closures indicate the quality of the post; they aren't attacks leveraged against users

I am really not sure it is wise to reopen unclear questions, whether this is from a new user or anyone for that matter.  A more constructive process is to leave a comments on how to improve the question, or direct the OP to chat (if they can access) to get additional guidance.

Reality is that we, as a collective entity, are very bad moderators. We are faceless, we are not transparent, we are slow, we are arbitrary. It is hard to imagine yet more worse experience for a first-time user, what we give them.
For example, the question closure. User gets the info that his question was rejected, but he also gets only cloudy, and very often utterly false reasons. Already this clearly shows for them: it does not matter, how hardly is he working to fix his question, he won't get  reopen. So, he does not invest the effort, rather leaves the site with bitter feelings.
We should be some... human interface of the site, with what the newcomer can talk and cooperate with them. Instead, we are an obstacle, user is coming for the content (and for the ears of the real professionals), our role is only to harass, suppress, obstruct him.
Anyone can see, what these guys say, by simply googling for critical content about the site network. There are also quite terrible horror stories.
In my opinion, not chatgpt is the largest competition to the site network today, but its own, irrational antagonism.
The company clearly visibly ignores the whole problem, maybe also they can not see a way out, or it is pretty fine for them. Only they know that.
We might try to convince other users with various moderation privileges: to be nice. And, instead of keeping everything with iron fist, what could expel a newbie, we should see them as potential worthy contributors of the future.
What could work imho very well: we should try to create such a human structure where we are working like a pyramide; or a ladder: everyone asks "upward" and answers "downward" (in skill level).

The difficulty here is those with access to the analytics can verify that, except for a strange uptick in downvotes in May 2024, the weekly number of downvotes has been roughly constant in time for the past 10 years.    So it’s not like downvoting (in absolute number) is a growing problem.  It is true that the number of questions is decreasing (broadly since May 2020) , but that could be an AI effect.  In other words, there is nothing to suggest things are much worse than 10 years ago in terms of downvoting, or downvoting newcomers.

On the other hand, although I am not as engaged as before with the site, my definite impression is that there are more “random questions” (aka non-mainstream aka check-my-pet theory), although I dunno how one could quantify my hunch.

I agree that this site has a problem with question closure. However, I think it should be separated from downvoting closed questions after closure. I do not understand up or down-voting a closed question. Closure should freeze everything for that question. I do not see a good reason for post-closure votes.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 in some cases it is well deserved.  I’m not completely sure there is a closure problem, or at least as I mention above what has changed to go from an acceptable situation to a “problem”.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I disagree. I don't see how this site has a "closure problem". In any case, since the reopen queue update in 2021 (which enabled users to submit a closed question for review upon editing), it has been much better than before. In addition, many users continue to be active in reopening.

I think it would interesting for someone who has access to the data, to find out how many newcomers never return to Physics SE after being "beaten up" and receiving a very unfriendly "welcome" to the site on their first few questions.

@KDP "Unwelcoming" complaints are not limited to PSE.  See this post and answers therein.

@KDP The data is not public. There is a https://data.stackexchange.com and also a regular data dump, but these don't contain the data (deleted content is not included, thus you can not see deleted first-posts and also you have no way to decide from a not deleted post if it was first-post). There could be some way to circumvent these limitations: 1) the sites could be continuously grabbed to get the data before deletion and 2) generous 10k+ users could help us to grab the already existing deleted posts. Both might be unwelcomed, but no one knows if it is actually allowed (my question about this

@KDP no one knows, why, I personally have some quite pretty ideas but nothing provable. On the level of the laissez faire capitalism we can say, it is up to them, how do they kill, what they have built up with a lot of work and once-in-a-life luck...

I assume "they" are running a business here and you would think that having a steady flow of new member and retaining them, was in their own best interests, long term. Maybe I'm wrong.

"These guys typically get itchy if they see that others collect reputation." This would be a great thing to discuss in a separate meta post if you have evidence that people who vote to delete answers are doing so to prevent those users from gaining reputation. Do you have a list of answers that should not have been deleted, and a common pattern showing the same users deleting answers to users who are gaining reputation at an alarming rate?

What if people are actually closing questions they think deserve to be closed based on their understanding of how the site works?

I honestly am so lost at this point. I vote to close questions if they meet a closure reason. I don't look at the reputation of the user or how long they have been on the site. I have no idea why we are talking about assigning morality to this decision.

@BioPhysicist Suddenly I remember the gypsies who have killed and eaten the swans of the Queen in the Themes. They said, the were free prey, their purpose was to be eaten by them. UK is a funny traditional country, they have a law (and also tradition) that all the swans on the Thames are the property of the Queen and killing them is high treason. Now pack these together. It looks, these sides won't ever understand each other.

@BioPhysicist classic peterh material here; lots of claims of abuse/evil but severely lacking evidence (with even more classic paranoid claims that such evidence exists but is intentionally hidden from everyone to cover up said abuses/evils). I would strongly encourage to not feed the trolls

@peterh I find your half-accusations to be pretty incredible I must say.

@BioPhysicist peterh has a long history of making vague unsubstantiated accusations about this site having an "inbred inner circle" who conspires (supposedly via closures and downvotes) to prevent new users from establishing themselves. Just take a look at their past posts here as well as on Meta.SE. I can say that in my entire history of using this site, I have not observed any evidence of such behavior.

...just take a look to the voting and review stats of these guys; particularly their upvote-downvote ratio and their usual decisions in the close/reopen reviews. QED

@peterh The fact that you've been on this site for over a decade (longer than myself) yet still fail to understand how it works leaves me with nothing else to say.

@VincentThacker The social mechanisms of this site network is that good-willing people is expelled, and that happens. It looks I am like a "last mohican" here. However, the visitor stats of the site network are very bad and worsening, it is tought to be caused by the chatgpt, while in the reality, it is caused by you. Partially by you, dear Vincent. However, it looks that is fine for the company (they could and should have long fixed you), but if that is fine for the company, it is up to them, how do they kill their own business.

@ZeroTheHero No, the stats of the site network are decreasing since 2014. It is not AI effect, more clearly explaining it with AI is a superficial explanation: we, humans are still much better as the chatgpt. The real cause of the so-named "ai effect" is that chatgpt does not say for a pretty okay physics question, that "it is homework/offtopic/anything, go away, you suck, you stupid looser". In theory, not even we say this, but believe me, exactly that is how our closures sound for the newcomers. It is only packaged into a polite form, but exactly that is what we say them. So they go away.

@peterh That is totally false. Questions are closed in order to (1) maintain an overall quality and (2) ensure that the site stays within a certain scope agreed by community consensus. This is what makes the site very useful to me. My position is it would be much worse without this moderation mechanism, even if it means turning away many users. In addition, closing questions is not the same as deleting them. The fact that you have failed to grasp this point for the past decade speaks for itself.

@VincentThacker That is the theory. The practice is that questions are closed to prevent the low-rep answerers from gaining rep and privileges. This is why is the site-overmoderated, why are questions closed with utterly false or contraproductive reasonings. The fact that you are working as part of this system, and your only defense against this very obvious argument is that you just copy-paste the 10001st time the same theoretical content, clearly shows that you are simply ineligible for a discussion about the topic.

@peterh "questions are closed to prevent the low-rep answerers from gaining rep and privileges" This is again totally false and unsubstantiated. A new user who posts legitimate answers will earn rep in the same amount as an established user. It is a simple fact that users with more knowledge will earn more rep over time as they can answer more questions and also with better quality.

@VincentThacker You do not disprove my statement, only react a generality, essentially replaying what you have already said. I think, the meaningful part of our discussion has already long ended. Go away and think a bit about, what I explained here. I stopped the talk with you here.

@peterh The burden is on you to prove your allegations. The fact that I have seen many new users start at 1 and reach 10-20k over time by writing good posts more than disproves your statements. Many of the >10k users here today started much later than the creation of this site. For you to repeatedly assert without evidence, for over a decade, there is some "conspiracy" is bordering on trolling to me. If you dislike this site so much, what makes you stay here?

Supporting @VincentThacker : I’m sorry but “ The practice is that questions are closed to prevent the low-rep answerers from gaining rep and privileges” does not hold water. Currently ~20 of the top 50 contributors by reputation have <10 years on the site.  This simply contradicts your assertion.   Plus, I it beyond me understand why someone who has been active on the site for 10ish years can continue to be active if the primary motivation is “to prevent the low-rep answerers from gaining rep and privileges”.

with respect: you make all kinds of allegations and insinuations, without any evidence. Additionally,  you are suggesting a conspiracy by very many, including me, based on your own interpretation of actions by isolated actors who have never met.  I do not know if I always do “some good” but I know for sure you certainly do not know better than I on that score.

@ZeroTheHero The reality is only that you can not tolerate critics in any form, you can not answer it, except with your reflexes ("without evidence", "conspricy theorist", blah-blah). The reality is only that you are terribly bad moderators, exactly because you are just building a clique, and not a media to distribute knowledge. You know it and I know it, but you won't ever admit it. Even your comments served only the purpose of demonstrating your loyalty to the clique, and not an equal discussion. On this reason, I think our talk ends here and now.

Yes it does.  I'm truly sorry you had to revert to personal unfounded comments as you have, not only towards me but towards other as well.

At this point I don't even know what is actually being claimed, and if I'm personally being attacked or not, haha. I'm not sure about any "clique"; I don't have any personal investment here nor interaction with any site members off line / IRL. All I know is that I enjoy answering questions on this site, and I individually think that the policies work nicely to form a site with a curated list of questions. Any site will have to have some sort of cut off for what is/isn't allowed. If one thinks the policies are too strict, then there are other sites for them, no hard feelings either way

@BioPhysicist You are not attacked and I think the answer is clear.

@BioPhysicist Yes and they are doing it. 10 years ago, SO/SE was a star on the sky of the internet. Now it is a decreasing crap from which everyone knows: there is no purpose to ask here anything, it will be closed and deleted on the spot. I think, the list of the deadly mistakes of the company is not long, but re-labeling the deletionist ruling cliques to "community" and taming them, instead of purging them, was probably their top. Now if you google for any educated layman physics question, the likely top google result is a reddit one and there you find your answer, 10 years ago it was PSE.

The fact that many questions are answered and not closed, and others are even reopened,  shows how disillusioned you are to say "there is no purpose to ask here anything, it will be closed and deleted on the spot." Even if PSE isn't "on top" anymore, that doesn't prove deep-rooted community conspiracies. In any case, I do enough in my own life to help others learn physics; I don't take this site seriously enough to think it's the only or best avenue for that. It is what it is. It doesn't define me or the state of physics though.

@BioPhysicist It only shows our cultural difference. I would like to point one of my pevious comments, about the romas who have eaten the birds of the queen on the Thames. You see that you just follow rules, so you are fine. What you never say, but we know, that you think it so: misusing the purpose of the site (media to distribute knowledge) for selfish reasons (mostly purpuse-less clique-building) is pretty okay for you, but not for us. We all see that; and your stats count very little, for example, for the newbies welcomed by this.

@BioPhysicist But I could also mention the unthinkable amount of pretty fine questions closed as "homework" or on any other utterly false, cloudy reason, but why? You have no answer for the critics, you do not even hear them, instead you initiate the "conspriacy" endless loop. I am happily closing this endless loop by ending the talk here also with you now.

The question you linked to was edited and reopened. The OP even recognized "I admit that my previous version of the question is rather not rigorous and have clarified the question." There are many "fine" questions that are closed; the process is far from perfect. But to take that and conclude personal attacks just doesn't follow.
